# Code conditionally to draw information from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-2016

I have two workbooks. I would like to dynamically draw information from one to the other. I've been researching for days and it seems the only way to do this is using Visual Basic, but I don't know how to use VB. I'm willing to learn, but someone needs to give me step-by-step instructions, preferably with screenshots, for how to do this.

Here's the specifics. I would like the code to check Workbook1, Sheet1, ColumnK for a particular value, let's say "West". If a row has "West" in ColumnK, I would like the entire row copied and pasted into Workbook2,Sheet2 in the next available row. I would like this to be dynamic so that whenever I add new information to Workbook1, the code checks and draws relevant info to Workbook2. If it cannot be drawn into Workbook2, I would instead like to draw it into Workbook1, Sheet2.

I just copied a code from another Stack Overflow thread that I got to work within the same Workbook1.

```vb
Sub CopyRow()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim x As Long
Dim MaxRowList As Long
Dim S As String
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet

Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ASK")
Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Petty Cash")

iCol = 1
MaxRowList = wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 3 To MaxRowList
    If InStr(1, wsSource.Cells(x, 11), "West") Then
    wsTarget.Rows(x).Value = wsSource.Rows(x).Value
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This will temporarily work for me, but if someone can show me how to edit the code so that the information is drawn into a separate workbook, that would be really helpful. I ask that you please use layman's terms (and screenshots) so that I can understand.

Comment: Uh there's similar problems with answers here at SO alone. Post the code you have been trying and you're far more likely to receive help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment findwindow. I just added a code that I found a few minutes ago and got to work after a fashion.

Comment: lol working for days but just found code a few minutes ago that works XD Well, since you said you're willing to learn, please study the code you found and determine what it's doing. Please feel free to inquire about a particular line if you can't decipher it. Edit: I am leaving in about half hour so I may not answer until tomorrow XD

Comment: I know, it's ironic, but my Google searches have been turning up more complex codes like [this one](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/copy-and-pasting-rows-in-excel-into-a-new-sheet/9205e851-2dd9-4da8-be3b-556e058afb88) that I couldn't understand.

Comment: In the code that is working for me now, it's drawing info from ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("ASK") and putting it in ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("Petty Cash"). Is there a way to change the destination from ThisWorkbook to another workbook?

Comment: Good. How is it putting it from one sheet to another. What line is doing that? And how does it know which sheet is which?

Comment: Line 12, or "Set wsTarget" is what designates the destination and the name "Petty Cash" tells which sheet to copy the data to within ThisWorkbook. If I change wsTarget to Destination.Worksheet("Petty Cash"), where "Destination" is the name of the other workbook, will it understand that command?

Comment: Nice. You got it! But hold your horses. You have to set the Destination first =P I am leaving but `set Destination=workbooks("theNameOfBookHere")` will do the job.

Comment: You are a lifesaver! I'll give that a try. If I have more questions, I may ask for your generosity again. Thank you for being so kind about this :-)

Comment: You're most welcome. I am more than happy to help those who try ^_^ I will be around tomorrow if you need more help.

Comment: Thank you very much. Have a great day!

Comment: Hi findwindow, I tried adding in the code you suggested, and it now looks like this:

Comment: `Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ASK")`
`Set Destination = Workbooks("Destination")`
`Set wsTarget = Destination.Worksheets("Expenses")`

Comment: But now I'm getting a Runtime Error 9: Subscript Out of Range. I think this means it cannot find the workbook "Destination." Do I need to include the file's location on my hard drive, like Users/name/desktop/Destination?

Comment: The destination workbook has to be open for the set to work. But yes, you can set it with a workbooks open giving full path and name.